# How can we use nodetool to find unbalance in cluster ?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I need to know if we can find if there is an unbalance in the cluster using the nodetool provided with cassandra 1.1.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nodetool ring` and pay attention to the **Owns** column.

```
lyubent:bin lyubentodorov$ ./nodetool ring
Note: Ownership information does not include topology, please specify a keyspace. 
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
127.0.0.1       datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  9.1 KB          100.00%             38783122578811068034129545515711073918
```

On a side note, if you are starting out with C* you should target more up-to-date versions.